# Page image half blocked on my laptop

Tags: browser, images

There is this site that generates images and graphs based on the data user enters. The images arent displaying well - they are half blocked - i'm able to see only half the image (but the page says all items have been loaded). I've tried using various browsers (chrome / IE / firefox). The strange part is - the images are displaying normally when i use my other laptop. I tried comparing the page source for the two, and they are the same ! Can anyone pl suggest on what is likely missing / going wrong ?

Thanks,
Trinity.

Comment: I cant add the screenshots and URL as they are CONFIDENTIAL. I'll try to describe - the image is in JPEG format. And, only part of it, near the top, with some arbitrary lower boundary, is visible. The rest is in grey shade.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the images didn't load properly the first time and were cached in that state. Try clearing the browser cache and load the page again. What you are seeing is a part-rendered JPEG image. The file format tells the browser how large the image will be and that space is reserved. Thus the gray part of the image is the part not downloaded.

Comment: Hit Control+R repeatedly until problem goes away.